# Shortcut key to rename a selected file?

Tags: shortcut-keys, pcmanfm

In PcManfm, is there some shortcut key to rename a selected file? <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Shortcut key to rename a file/folder in PCManFM is <kbd>F2</kbd>.  The same as in Windows, which is handy if you use both.

Comment: Thanks. BUt what does it mean that "R" in "Rename" after right clicking a file is underscored?

Comment: @Tim That seems to be a keyboard shortcut that you can use and just press R after you right-click on a file.  However, you don't have to right-click at all if you just press F2 after selecting it.

Comment: where can I find all the available keyboard shortcuts, including F2?

Comment: That's also the shortcut to rename files in Nautilus (and its  forks), Dolphin and Thunar. It's also a common shortcut to edit the currently selected list entry or table cell in many other applications (e. g. MS Excel and LO/OO Calc).

Comment: @Tim I've never found an official list of all keyboard shortcuts, however, by navigating through the menus, you can see what the shortcuts are.  For example, if you click on the EDIT menu, you can see F2 beside it which denotes that this is the shortcut key for it.

Comment: The underlined R in menues can be shortcut "clicked" with `ALT+R` usually